# Updating Costmap2D with a static map

Tags: navigation, exploration, costmap-2d, costmap, clear-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm working on exploration of unknown maps with mobile robots. I would like to know if there is a way to update a costmap from a static map (e.g. the one created by gmapping) in place of using the `observation_sources` parameter, while also keeping the `track_unknown_space` parameter to true.

I need this because otherwise sometimes my exploration costmap gets noisy. As an alternative can the [clear_costmap_recovery](http://wiki.ros.org/clear_costmap_recovery?distro=hydro) be used for a custom costmap in order to reinitialize the map from a static map?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129906/updating-costmap2d-with-a-static-map/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 808 on 2014-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well observation_source could be used to use for example scan data to create a map. This might be used for the local costmap. As you use the static parameter, the costmap depends on NO other data then a published map(from gmapping for example).
So if you want to create a global_costmap set the static parameter to true. By increasing the update and publish frequency you can keep the costmap up to date more accurately.

The tracking of unknown_space is independent to an observation_source or whether you use static or a rolling_window approach.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [dneuhold](https://answers.ros.org/users/5295/dneuhold/) with karma: 205 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0